# How to monitor Flash applets?

Tags: monitoring, flash, uptime

We created a fancy Flash application for a customer and deployed it. The server itself is monitored by the hosting company, but is there any external monitoring service that works well with **Flash applets**? We want to test that (a) the Flash app is working ok and (b) monitor and log its performance.